# game loop not working ncurses

Tags: c++, c, loops

I'm new to ncurses and we have a project to create a game of our choice. 
The idea of my game is to have a spaceship and have enemies attack from the top.
I only started the code and I already ran into a problem, when i use the space bar to shoot a bullet, the bullet will travel, however i am unable to move my ship at the same time the bullet is moving.

```
#include<ncurses.h>

typedef struct
{/*define a structure for player information*/
    int row;
    int col;
}playerinfo;

int changeRow(int x,int m, int c)
{
    if(x+m==22 || x+m==0  )
    {
        beep();
        return x;
    }
    return x+m;
}
int changeColumn(int y,int n, int r)
{
    if(y+n==72 || y+n==0  )
    {   
        beep();
        return y;
    }
    return y+n;
}

int main(){
    initscr();              

    start_color();  
    assume_default_colors(COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK); 

    noecho();
    cbreak();                       

    curs_set(0); /* turn cursor display off */

    timeout(0); 

    keypad(stdscr,TRUE);  /* allow keypad keys to be used */            
    playerinfo playership;

    playership.row= 10;
    playership.col= 15;

    char player[] ="     X     ";
    char player2[]="    |o|    ";
    char player3[]="  xX| |Xx  ";
    char player4[]="  X | | X  ";
    char player5[]=" X__-|-__X ";

    char bullet = '.';

    int key = 0;
    int i=0;
    bool moving= false;
    mvprintw(playership.row,playership.col,player);
    mvprintw(playership.row+1,playership.col,player2);
    mvprintw(playership.row+2,playership.col,player3);
    mvprintw(playership.row+3,playership.col,player4);
    mvprintw(playership.row+4,playership.col,player5);
    timeout(0);

    while(key!='q'){ 
        usleep(17000);

    mvprintw(playership.row,playership.col,"         ");
    mvprintw(playership.row+5,playership.col,"          ");

    key = getch (); 

    switch(key){ 
        case KEY_UP: playership.row=changeRow(playership.row,-1,playership.col); /* move up */ 
            break; 
        case KEY_DOWN: playership.row=changeRow(playership.row,+1,playership.col); /* move down */ 
            break; 
        case KEY_LEFT:playership.col=changeColumn(playership.col,-1,playership.row); /* move left */ 
            break; 
        case KEY_RIGHT:playership.col=changeColumn(playership.col,+1,playership.row); /* move right */ 
            break; 
        case ' ': moving=true; break;
            default: break; /* do nothing if other keys */ 
    }

    mvprintw(playership.row,playership.col,player);
    mvprintw(playership.row+1,playership.col,player2);
    mvprintw(playership.row+2,playership.col,player3);
    mvprintw(playership.row+3,playership.col,player4);
    mvprintw(playership.row+4,playership.col,player5);

    if (moving==true){
        for( i=0; i <24; i++){ 
            refresh; mvprintw(playership.row-i-2,playership.col+5,"%c", bullet); mvprintw(playership.row,playership.col,player); 
            refresh();usleep(12000); mvprintw(playership.row-i-1,playership.col+5," ");} moving=false; }
            refresh(); 
        }


    echo();   /* turn echo back on */

    endwin(); /* End curses mode */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did my best to edit formatting. May want to look over it.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you nested the "firing" code inside your game loop, so all input stops while you do that animation.  You need to change your logic to a kind of state machine:

```
    switch(key)
    {
    // ...
    case ' ':
        if( !bullet_active )
        {
            bullet_active = true;
            bullet_pos = 0;
        }
        break;
    }

    if( bullet_active ) {
        // TODO: Draw bullet at bullet_pos

        if( ++bullet_pos == 24 ) bullet_active = false;
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much! it worked, the only problem now is that i can't fire more than one bullet at a time.

Comment: It's pretty normal to have a maximum number of active bullets at one time (Space Invaders is an example).  If you want multiple bullets, then use an array for `bullet_pos`.  You can work out the logic in there.  I suggest that you have `N` free bullet slots and limit the firing rate (*eg* you can't fire another bullet until all active bullet positions are larger than some value).  You update, hit-test and draw each bullet in the array.  When that bullet is finished, reset its position so you know that slot is available again (you can use `-1` for this - the `bullet_active` flag is redundant).

Comment: That's fine.  I'm not sure why you asked about multiple bullets when the code you originally supplied wasn't designed for that either.  Put it this way.  If you can have 5 bullets at once, you need to store their positions.  If you have `int bullet_pos[5]` that would be fine.  You could use `-1` in each position to say that no bullets are active.  Then when you want to fire one you search the array to find the first position that is `-1` and change it to `0`.  When you draw the bullets, you go through the array and draw a bullet for any position that is not `-1`, and update its position.

Comment: i tried what you said, it worked , i have more than one bullet now, however the latest bullet fired is the only one moving, the rest will stop in their place. im really sorry if im being a bother for you.

Comment: It's probably time you posted this as a new question.  Show the code that starts a bullet, and the code to update/draw.